# Translating Url to another language for SEO purposes in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, translation

I am developing web app using asp.net mvc4. The plan for the future is that it will be multi-language app. The names of all controllers and actions are in english but I want to translate url to my native language(Slovak) because of SEO purposes and I want to leave the names of controllers and actions in english.

So for example I want to change the url **home/about** to **uvod/o_nas** (slovak translation)

I spent some time on google, but I was not able to find any comprehensive solution so I want to ask for help here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add language specific routes to achieve that.

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default", 
url: "uvod/o_nas/{id}", 
defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
                action = "About", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, so simple and elegant :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a project I've done that does this with attributes and reflection. It allows you to maintain a more sane route map.

https://github.com/mwardrop/MVC4BilingualURLS

We maintain a French and English version of all urls with 3 routes.

Comment: This is an interesting solve. I don't like the looping for strings, however, I much prefer this than having to add dozens perhaps hundreds of separate foreign language routes to my RouteConfig file. I am going to implement this solution in my code. All in all a solid solution.

Just a note I translated this from VB to C# and had to make a couple alterations to get it to work. Not sure if it was a bug in the original code but there are a couple areas in the Utilities class that I think are coded wrong. At least I couldn't make it work without changing it a little.